# getAttributeNode() and getAttributeNodeNS() warnings

Tags: javascript, warnings

My page opens properly but in FF I'm continuously getting warning

```
[10:44:54.904] Use of getAttributeNode() is deprecated. Use getAttribute() instead. @ http://localhost/admin/?page=add#
[10:46:23.828] Use of getAttributeNodeNS() is deprecated. Use getAttributeNS() instead. @ http://localhost/admin/?page=add
```

Btw i'm using CKeditor. What does mean that warning? and how to fix it?
[image]

Comment: I'm getting the same warning using Mootools 1.4.5 (latest at the time of writing) in Joomla 3.1

Answer (score 5):

Those two methods are deprecated in Firefox 7 because they have been [removed in DOM4](http://www.w3.org/TR/domcore/#dom-core), the current version of the DOM spec. It is likely that eventually they will be removed from Firefox and possibly other browsers.

If the warnings are coming from CKEditor code, I'm sure the CKEditor team will be aware of this and release an update at some point that does not use these methods. However, I couldn't find any use of this method in CKEditor's source code, so it's more likely to be coming from something else you're including on your page. Possibly CKFinder, which does seem to use that method?

Comment: Chrome also gives a depreciation warning about getAttributeNode() nowadays.

Answer (score 3):

It seems to me that it's an internal problem in Firefox, at least one of the warnings is fixed in https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=690120 so we just have to wait and test with the new Firefox versions :-)

Comment: You're right. I'm quite surprised: I tend to assume such an error must be the fault of the web developer rather than the browser developer, because that is usually the case. Not this time.

Comment: The surprising part was that the warning did slip to the release version instead of being fixed while in alpha or beta. I guess that everyone that saw it at the beginning thought that it was due to a problem in the pages instead of looking at the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Use of `getAttributeNode()` is deprecated. Use getAttribute()`enter code here` instead. @ http://localhost/admin/?page=add#

Use of `getAttributeNodeNS()` is deprecated. Use `getAttributeNS()` instead. @ http://localhost/admin/?page=add