# Use of getAttributeNodeNS() is deprecated. Use getAttributeNS() instead

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I'm working on a website, and using jQuery to display pop-ups.

When clicking on an article on the website, it should load a pop-up. The following code is used for that purpose:

```js
var popup = jQuery(this).attr('rel'); 
jQuery('.window').append("http://www.perimetro.com.ar/-previa/"+popup+""); 
jQuery('.adentro').load(popup);
```

...but the pop-up is blocked and this error appears in the firebug console:

> Use of getAttributeNodeNS() is deprecated. Use getAttributeNS() instead

What's going on here?

Comment: Deprecated doesn't usually mean "broken," just that perhaps the method was renamed or a newer implementation was provided. Which version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: im using v1.4.4, it load the popup but doent show.

Answer (score 13):

[A ticket was opened](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/10735) with jQuery about the warning that is displayed in the console. The short of it is that the jQuery team doesn't believe it's them causing the issue, but the firebug console itself.

<strike>If your popup is blocked it's probably due to the way you're launching it, or the browser is blocking it from opening.</strike>

UPDATE: There are various questions and bug reports associated with this issue at various places; the comments and discussions taking place may help shed some light on the OP's question:

1. https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=661327
2. https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=690120
3. [getAttributeNode() and getAttributeNodeNS() warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7789847/74757)
4. [Firefox warning message](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8295610/74757)

Comment: this has nothing to do with the firebug console, or jQuery. it's the user-agent, see my answer on this.

Answer (score 5):

This is *neither a problem with FireFox, nor a fault in jQuery*. It's a **DOM interface issue**, due to breaking changes in DOM level 4 API.

See this post for additional information:

- [getAttributeNode() and getAttributeNodeNS() warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7789847/getattributenode-and-getattributenodens-warnings)

#### Reference

- [DOM core specs on W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/domcore/#dom-core)