# Firefox warning message

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebug, html

I have a weird issue with firebug with my current javascript code

I have a web page with javascript and jQuery and I get this message:

> use of getattributenodens is deprecated. use getattributens instead

I use jQuery 1.5.2 and Firefox 8, I get this error also on Windows 7 and XP. I tried mac also

I don't use `getattributenodens` in my code,

Who can fix this error? Thanks

[image]

Comment: read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7789847/getattributenode-and-getattributenodens-warnings

Comment: there isn't anything wrong with your code, it's a jQuery's issue. You check this ticket here http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/10735

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use of getAttributeNodeNS() is deprecated. Use getAttributeNS() instead](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8095495/use-of-getattributenodens-is-deprecated-use-getattributens-instead)

Comment: They think it's actually a firebug issue, I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: If you don't already know, you can turn them off. Click on the arrow on the Console tab and select what you want to be displayed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Its just a warning, so developers can update their code with plenty of time.

You are a fair few versions behind in jQuery. If you upgrade to the current version (1.7.1), I think you will find this error message no longer exists.

Visit jQuery Website - http://www.jquery.com

Direct link to newest version — http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js

Comment: With firefox 8.0.1 and jquery 1.7.1 the warning persists.
On jquery main site too. http://jquery.com/

Comment: How can this be an accepted answer, this answer is just wrong.