# fancybox not working in firefox

Tags: jquery, fancybox

i have been looking into this for a bit now and have become stuck.

i have loaded a simple fancybox pop up onto my site, it works perfect in IE9 and Chrome but for some reason its not working at all in firefox.

i am running this locally at the moment using IIS

the code for the incudes are:

```
<script type="text/javascript"src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    /* This is basic - uses default settings */

    $("a.imagepop").fancybox();

});
</script>
```

and the html is:

```
<a class="imagepop" href="/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/imageTest1.png"><img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-30" title="imageTest1" src="http://localhost:8084/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/imageTest1.png" alt="" width="327" height="328" /></a>
```

i have tried to use firebug but all its telling me is: Use of getAttributeNodeNS() is deprecated. Use getAttributeNS() instead.

Comment: What version of Firefox are you using? Have you tried using FancyBox 2 rather than 1.3.4?

Comment: ill try that one, and was on ff7 just upgraded to 8

Comment: I have just tried with Firefox latest version 9 and works well! and which version are you using?And have you included the "CSS".

Comment: updated to FB2, now all works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I did and worked fine in Firefox:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="jquery.fancybox-1.3.4/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css" rel="stylesheet"
        type="text/css" />
    <script src="jquery.fancybox-1.3.4/fancybox/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.4.pack.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="jquery.fancybox-1.3.4/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js" type="text/javascript"></script>



    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        /* This is basic - uses default settings */

        $("a.imagepop").fancybox();

    });
    </script>

    <div>
    <a class="imagepop" href="http://wallpapers.leovacity.be/images/Beautiful_flowers.jpg"><img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-30" title="imageTest1" src="http://wallpapers.leovacity.be/images/Beautiful_flowers.jpg" alt="" width="327" height="328" /></a>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

[According to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7789847/getattributenode-and-getattributenodens-warnings), it's a problem with Firefox 7. How about using [FancyBox 2 instead](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/)?

**Edit:** Using FancyBox 2 with Firefox 7 works fine for me locally.

Comment: thank you both i have just updated to FB2 and it works a treat... did not know that there was a v2

Answer (score 0):

Have you included other JS files in the page? If yes, try removing them. I have never  experienced issues in FF but other scripts may cause problems.

Answer (score 0):

When I have problems with Fancybox iFrame popup not working in Firefox like it does in Chrome or IE I usually added this to the html header of the iFrame popup page and then it often works in Firefox:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

Answer (score 0):

move references of your 3rd party libraries(i.e. jquery controls) prior to fancybox libraries on the page.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't post identical answers to multiple questions. Post one good answer, then vote/flag to close the other questions as duplicates. If the question is not a duplicate, *tailor your answers to the question.*