# DOM Level 2 and 3 Core support in IE?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dom

I just discovered that some old javascript code that uses `.setAttributeNode` is broken. 
Internet Explorer (tested in IE10) gives an error (unknown attribute) while FireFox warns that it is deprecated.

RienNeVaPlu͢s pointed me to documentation that says that DOM Level 4 Core has dropped `.setAttributeNode` [along with a bunch of other methods](http://www.w3.org/TR/domcore/#historical).

I tried searching for documentation on when and why MS dropped DOM Level 3 Core compatibility. After checking the latest patches, I think it broke with the [MS15-009](http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/3034196) patch released Feb 10th 2015, but I haven't confirmed that.

Can anyone confirm if all [deprecated methods](http://www.w3.org/TR/domcore/#historical) have been removed or if it is just some of them?

Here is a list of methods that could be affected:

Interface members:

Node

```
    hasAttributes()
    attributes
    namespaceURI
    prefix
    localName
    isSupported
    getFeature()
    getUserData()
    setUserData()
    isSameNode()
```

Document

```
    createCDATASection()
    createAttribute()
    createAttributeNS()
    createEntityReference()
    inputEncoding
    xmlEncoding
    xmlStandalone
    xmlVersion
    strictErrorChecking
    domConfig
    normalizeDocument()
    renameNode()
```

DOMImplementation

```
    getFeature()
```

Attr

```
No longer inherits from Node and therefore completely changed.
```

Element

```
    getAttributeNode()
    getAttributeNodeNS()
    setAttributeNode()
    removeAttributeNode()
    schemaTypeInfo
    setIdAttribute()
    setIdAttributeNS()
    setIdAttributeNode()
```

DocumentType

```
    entities
    notations
    internalSubset
```

Text

```
    isElementContentWhitespace
    replaceWholeText()
```

**Update:**

I have tested some more and found that old style events also don't work.

**Update 2:**

I have tested on IE10 and IE11 and the behaviour is the same, they both seem to be adhering to DOM Level 4 Core.
You can revert to an older DOM level by activating the Compatibility Mode in the browser (emulating IE7), but that also means that the new features are unavailable.

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/domcore/#dom-core - see [also](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7789847/getattributenode-and-getattributenodens-warnings)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a code issue, it's general knowledge

Comment: I think this might be a hot issue for a while. There are probably more people out there who didn't know this. Anyway, I have updated the question to make it easier to find.

Comment: Please note that support for *setAttributeNode* was introduced in the W3C DOM 2 specification, it is deprecated in the W3C DOM 4 **draft** and in the WHATWG [*living standard*](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org). It remains part of the DOM 3 standard. You also don't say what version of IE has dropped support and I can't find any reference on MSDN saying support has been removed, only that it was [*introduced in IE 6*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288603(v=vs.85).aspx), so it's removal may be an error.

Comment: Thanks RobG. I've updated my question with the IE version where I found the problem (IE10). I haven't tried it on other IE versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems all major browsers switched to W3C DOM 4 in the beginning of 2015.

To be compatible, you need to use the new DOM structure on your web site.

Users browsing with Internet Explorer can enable `Compatibility Mode` to emulate IE7 and use DOM 3 (tested on IE10 and IE11).