# AngularJs : Autofocus not working in firefox

Tags: javascript, angularjs

here is simple directive for autofocus :

```
app.directive('autoFocus', function($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'AC',
        link: function(_scope, _element) {
            $timeout(function(){
                _element[0].focus();
            }, 0);
        }
    };
});
```

Demo :  http://jsfiddle.net/ounsqcmt/55/

This directive works great in Chrome but doesn't work in Firefox . `version 36.00`
Any idea ?

Comment: $timeout(function(){
                 window.focus()
                _element[0].focus();
            }, 0);

Answer (score 0):

it shows a warning in firefox:
"Use of getAttributeNode() is deprecated. Use getAttribute() instead."

It seems that it's an internal problem in Firefox, at least one of the warnings is fixed in https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=690120 . 
The problem was raised with jQuery too about the warning that is displayed in the console.

http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/12072

but it shows that bug has been fixed by their end.

This might also neither a problem with FireFox, nor a fault in jQuery. It might be DOM interface issue, due to breaking changes in DOM level 4 API.

[See this stack overflow link for additional information:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7789847/getattributenode-and-getattributenodens-warnings)

Comment: sorry, I didn't updated the link properly in last line. Yes I am sure about it. This kind of issue has been raised already (see shared stack overflow link in last line, answer given by Tim Down)

Comment: Thanks, so what's the solution?

Answer (score 0):

```js
var app = angular.module("App", []);

app.controller("AppCtrl", function($scope) {
       
})

app.directive('autoFocus', function($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'AC',
        link: function(_scope, _element) {
          
            $timeout(function(){
                 window.focus()
                _element[0].focus();
            }, 0);
        }
    };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="App" ng-controller="AppCtrl ">
    <form>
        
        <input type="text" />
        <input name="theInput" auto-focus />
        
    </form>
    
    

  


</div>
```